# Errors in importing Tensorflow in Python script

Tags: python, xcode, tensorflow

I want to make a python script containing TensorFlow. I use xcode10.2 beta as an editor.
I did set up xCode correctly and it runs python scripts.
I installed Tensorflow 1.13.1 using pip install --user TensorFlow's.
I also installed NumPy on the same location (pip install --user numpy)
I check the locations and the are both in /users/Theo/library etc.
I check all dependencies , fixed them all and checked with pip check tensorflow and it reports no broken chains.

[image: screenshot of installation]

I import both in the script
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
No i get the following errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/Theo/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/Theo/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 52, in 
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/Theo/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in 
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
Program ended with exit code: 1

Any suggestions what this might be?
Theo

Comment: the error message shows you don't have module google.protobuf

Comment: After checking it seems that some frameworks where installed in /library/..etc and some at /users/Theo/library/..etc.  Checking the frameworks dit not show a problem but in running them it did. So I uninstalled all the frameworks and installed them again with pip install --user. Now it works.  Thanks for pointing in the right direction.